# JPQL SELECT not retrieving the updated data

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have a controller method that does these two operations:

1. updates customer name
2. retrieves the updated customer from the db

```
customerRepository.updateCustomerName(customerId, name);
Customer updatedCustomer = customerRepository.searchCustomer(customerId);
```

These are the respective repository methods:

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Customer c SET c.name = ?2 WHERE c.customerId = ?1")
public int updateCustomerName(Long customerId, String name);

@Query("SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.customerId =?1")
public Customer searchCustomer(Long customerId);
```

The update is working fine.

When executed, the name is correctly updated in the database.

The problem I'm facing is that the searchCustomer method is returning the Customer object with the old data (the name it had before the update).

Not sure why.

Shouldn't this code query the db again and retrieve the updated data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try
`@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)`
To clear the cache and force a new select against the database in the next queries

And maybe you should use `flushAutomatically = true` to flush entities before your query

Comment: Perfect! That was exactly the issue. Just accepted the answer. Thank you.